# How to layout text of a range between two date formats

Tags: java, swing, layout, text

I'm currently writing a calendar / date picker implementation and I was wondering if anyone knows of a faster / easier way to achieve the following effect.

eg.

`05/02/2012 - 11/02/2012`

The effect I'm after is for the dividers (`/`) to always remain in the same place, and for the values to always fit in between them. This makes it much easier to follow when you're scrolling through weeks, because the font is not monospace.

The way I'm currently doing it seems over the top but it works.
I'm optimizing / refactoring and came across it thinking there must be a better way to do it.

Here's what I have:

```
  //getText() return a range in the format dd/mm/yyyy - dd/mm/yyyy

  String firstHalf = getText().substring(0, 10);
  String secondHalf = getText().substring(getText().length() - 10);

  int yOff = baseLine - ((showSubtext) ? 5 : 0);

  int slashWidth = fm.stringWidth("/");
  String a, b, c, d, e, f;
  int A, B, C, D, ax, bx, cx, dx, ex, fx;

  a = firstHalf.substring(0, 2);
  b = firstHalf.substring(3, 5);
  c = firstHalf.substring(6);
  d = secondHalf.substring(0, 2);
  e = secondHalf.substring(3, 5);
  f = secondHalf.substring(6);

  int sideGap = 45;
  int fieldWidth = 28;
  int leftOffset = 4;

  A = sideGap + fieldWidth;
  B = A + fieldWidth + slashWidth / 2;
  D = getWidth() - A - 20;
  C = D - fieldWidth - slashWidth / 2;

  ax = A - fm.stringWidth(a);
  bx = ((B - A) - fm.stringWidth(b)) / 2 + A + slashWidth / 2 + 1;
  cx = B + slashWidth;

  dx = C - fm.stringWidth(d);
  ex = ((D - C) - fm.stringWidth(e)) / 2 + C + slashWidth / 2 + 1;
  fx = D + slashWidth;

  g.drawString("/", A - leftOffset, yOff);
  g.drawString("/", B - leftOffset, yOff);
  g.drawString("/", C, yOff);
  g.drawString("/", D, yOff);

  g.drawString(a, ax - leftOffset, yOff);
  g.drawString(b, bx - leftOffset, yOff);
  g.drawString(c, cx - leftOffset, yOff);
  g.drawString(d, dx, yOff);
  g.drawString(e, ex, yOff);
  g.drawString(f, fx, yOff);
```

**Effect:**
[image: Image effect]

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like gross overkill. Why not just use a SimpleDateFormat and a monospaced font?

Comment: I agree completely, which is why I decided to ask about it. If there's an easy way to do it using a non-monospaced font, that would be the ideal. The obvious compromise would be to simply use a monospaced font.

Comment: Even proportionally spaced fonts typically give the digit glyphs a constant advance.

Comment: That's so spot on! +1. When I came up with the overkill solution I was using a different font, which did not give the digit glyphs a constant advance. After switching to another font family, I didn't think to check if they do have a constant advance. Sure enough, they seem to. So thanks, post an answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even proportionally spaced fonts typically give the digit glyphs a constant advance. The UI default or the actual [`Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) for a given logical family are fairly reliable. As @Hovercraft comments, you can then leverage all the considerable benefits of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).